Group of time translations for finite-dimensional quantum systems and incommensurable eigenvalues
I am a bit confused by the group of the time translations in finite-dimensional quantum mechanics. Take a finite-dimensional Hamiltonian H. For instance, for a two-dimensional system
$$
H=\begin{pmatrix}
e_1 & 0 \\
0 & e_2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The time evolution operator is $U(t)=\exp(-i H t)$. Then, I define the time translation symmetry as
$$
U(t) H U^\dagger(t) = H.
$$
My question is, what is the group formed by $G=\{U(t)\}_{t=-\infty}^\infty$ for general $e_1$ and $e_2$? We can easily see that this set indeed forms a group:
$$
U(0)=\mathbb{I},\quad U(t_1)U(t_2)=U(t_1+t_2)\in G,\quad U(t_1)U(-t_1)=\mathbb{I}.
$$
It seems to me that all the issues arise from the scenarios in which one of the eigenvalues is irrational. For instance, if $H=\sigma_z$ (or $H=\sigma_x$, as the choice of basis should not matter), then the group spanned by $e^{-i t \sigma_z}$ is a two-dimensional representation of $U(1)$ that is the direct sum of two irreducible representations, and we can restrict $t\in[0,2\pi)$. Next, assume that both $e_1=\frac{a_1}{b_1}$ and $e_2=\frac{a_2}{b_2}$. Then, we should still find that the group is a representation of $U(1)$ by taking $t\in[0,2\pi \times \text{lcm}(b_1,b_2) )$. However, let us now suppose that the eigenvalues are incommensurable. Then, clearly $G$ cannot be a representation of $U(1)$ anymore. Is it a representation of the group of spatial translations, as any element with different $t$ is not equal to any other element for $t\in(-\infty,\infty)$? If not, what is this group/what is it a representation of?

I'm not really sure what the difficulty here is, as you've already said everything relevant: ${U(t)}$ is a one-dimensional Lie group, and there are only two one-dimensional Lie groups: $\mathrm{U}(1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$. If there is a $t$ such that $U(t) = U(0)$, it's a $\mathrm{U}(1)$, otherwise it's $\mathbb{R}$ (here: if the eigenvalues are incommensurable). What exactly is the question?

Sorry, not being an expert at all in representation theory I just had doubts about my reasoning. Do you have a reference about the existence of only two one-dimensional Lie groups (I guess it comes quickly from their algebra?), and in particular a reference that discusses the two different finite-dimensional representations depending on the incommensurability of the eigenvalues? Thanks

Not a group theory person, but here are my thoughts on the problem.
For general $e_1$ and $e_2$, when is the function $U\left(t\right)$ one-to-one?
If $U\left(t_{1}\right)=U\left(t_{2}\right)$ then $\begin{cases}
e^{ie_{1}t_{1}}=e^{ie_{1}t_{2}}\\
e^{ie_{2}t_{1}}=e^{ie_{2}t_{2}}
\end{cases}$, hence $\begin{cases}
e_{1}t_{1}=e_{1}t_{2}+2\pi k\\
e_{2}t_{1}=e_{2}t_{2}+2\pi j
\end{cases}$ where $j,k\in\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\frac{e_{1}}{e_{2}}=\frac{e_{1}\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}{e_{2}\left(t_{1}-t_{2}\right)}=\frac{k}{j}\in\mathbb{Q}$.
So, $U$ is one-to-one $\iff$ $\frac{e_{1}}{e_{2}}\in\mathbb{Q}$.
In the case of $\frac{e_{1}}{e_{2}}\in\mathbb{Q}$, $U\left(t\right)$ has a finite period and the group $G=\left(\left\{ U\left(t\right)|t\in\mathbb{R}\right\} ,\,\cdot\right)$ is isomorphic to $U\left(1\right)$ like you showed. In the case $\frac{e_{1}}{e_{2}}\notin\mathbb{Q}$, let's show that the $G$ is isomorphic to $\left(\mathbb{R},+\right)$, with the group isomorphism being $U\left(t\right)$. We know that $U(t)$ in this case is one-to-one, and it is a homomorphism because $U\left(t_{1}+t_{2}\right)=U\left(t_{1}\right)U\left(t_{2}\right)$.
